# Confusion about the Link Register content during exceptions in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm, pipeline, arm7

I can't understand how the link register of the exception mode is updated during the exception.
Why for the SVC, Prefetch Abort and Undefined Instruction, the LR is having PC + 4 but for the Data Abort it's having PC + 8?

I was thinking maybe the PC is sampled by the exception at the decoding stage of the pipeline but because for the Data Abort we can't confirm that we had an error until the execution stage, PC at the time of the exceution is at the address of 2 instructions ahead which is getting fetched.
but for other exceptions and even branch instructions, in the decoding stage we can confirm that the PC is going to be updated so we can take a sample of PC at the decoding stage to put the sample into the LR in case the faulty or branch instruction goes to the execution stage. Am i understanding it correctly?

Comment: This difference may have at some point been dictated by the hardware, but by now it is architectural and must be preserved for compatibility regardless of whether the CPU still works this way or not.

Comment: Compatibility is a definite reason for this feature.  I am not 100% sure it is useless for an ARM7.  The data abort occurs at later stages (possibly much later in the case of a store with an in-precise abort).  A whole host of issues could occur such as a mode change.  Undoing this could be difficult, so DABT+8, could still be useful to keep the area limited to handle things, even in this day and age.  Certainly over all ARM designs this is the case.  For an ArmV7, it may not be true (but compatibility is).